# Can a vote to close be overridden?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question and when I later came back to view the site again I noticed that my vote did not appear on the screen. When I attempted to vote a second time the screen told me that I had already voted to close. But, again, my vote did not appear.

Was this an erroneous glitch in the system or was my vote to close overridden by some means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I VTC'ed to close the question (along with you), but the OP edited it sufficiently (to my liking at least).  In this case, I think it's appropriate to flag for other moderators attention if you think I made a mistake.

No glitches as far as I can tell, it's just an annoying power of moderatorship to obfuscate things we don't necessarily want to.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Up-voted +1. And accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities:

1. If you accidentally retracted your close vote you won't be able to vote to close it again.
2. If a question was closed (possibly by a moderator) and then quickly reopened, your close vote would be considered to have succeeded, and you wouldn't be allowed to vote again.
3. I forget the exact timing, but close votes expire after about a week if the question doesn't get enough for it to be closed. You can vote to close again, but not immediately, you have to wait a month.

The question's history page might show you what happened.